# "Request not supported" in IPCONFIG (WinXP SP3)

Tags: networking, windows-xp

In a customer PC (Windows XP SP3), suddenly the network went down: the network adapter appears with an error mark. I replaced the network card, but the new one does the same
thing.

When I enter IPCONFIG, XP shows this error (in standard and safe mode):

```
Internal error occurred 
Request not supported 
Unable to query host name
```

If I start the system with a boot cd the PC runs fine, so the problem seems to be in the XP installation.

I tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling the network card in the Device Manager
- disabling and reenabling the card
- netsh int ip reset
- netsh winsock reset catalog
- and a couple of "reset" programs (WinsockxpFix.exe, etc)

with no luck.

Is there any way to fix it without reinstalling XP?

TIA,
Pablo

Comment: Were any windows updates (automatically) installed recently that could have broken it? (history available @ http://update.microsoft.com)

Comment: @iainlbc: no, Windows Update is disabled

Answer (score 2):

I would have bet the Winsockfix would have done it.  It sounds like the TCP stack is screwed up.  [Have you tried this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259)?

Answer (score 0):

I like uslackrs response since it has the fixitnow thing!